# Add an ID to a template-part from Wordpress FSE

Tags: wordpress

I want to add an ID to a template part with Wordpress Full Site Editing.

The file for the template part is located here /parts/template.html.
I call the template part inside my template page, which is located here /templates/page.html, using this code:

```
<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"template","className":"template"} /-->
```

This outputs the following:

```
<div class="template wp-block-template-part">
```

I want to add the ID to this output, to get this result:

```
<div id="my-ID" class="template wp-block-template-part">
```

How is this possible?

*Edit: I don't want a wrapper and Javascript should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You said that you don't want a wrapper. Unfortunately, and [according to the Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/block-patterns/), it looks like ID is not an option at this time. I really hope someone proves me wrong because I need to do the same thing. For now, I kind of use a wrapper hack. From your example, when I call this template part:

```
<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"template","className":"template"} /-->
```

My FSE block theme contains this file: templates/template.html

Inside of there, the first thing I do is make a block as a div that uses my ID. It adds an extra div to my markup, but at least I can have my ID.

```
<!-- wp:group {"layout":{"type":"default"}} -->
<div id="my-hack-wrapper" class="wp-block-group">
    [the rest of my template content goes here]
</div>
<!-- /wp:group -->
```

FWIW: I am using WP 6.3.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your little hack. As you already said: this adds a wrapper, which I don't want. Maybe they will add this in the future.